# Unable to adjust margins in combined boxplot & histogram

Tags: r, histogram, boxplot

I need to plot a combined boxplot and histogram. While I am able to plot them together I am unable to do print the xlabel abd ylabel in the histogram. Every time I try to adjust the margins I get the  error 'figure margins too large'. Here is the code snippet

```
value <- rnorm(300,mean=100,sd=20)
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(1,3)) 
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))
boxplot(value, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE,ylim=c(0,160), 
      frame=F, col = "green1")
hist(value,breaks=40,xlab="Runs",ylab="Runs frequency", main = "Score")
```

Value takes a value between 0 to 250.

I am including the plot below. Do let me know how I can adjust the margins for this

Thanks
Ganesh[image]

Comment: The code provided does not plot those together. Give us the full code in order to test the margins. Also, please provide a sample for `value` and `batman$runs` to check against it.

Comment: It is the entire code. As I said the value ranges from  0 to 250. The other part is irrelevant

Comment: I don't know how you combine those two together but the problem with the histogram is that it is too big for the x and y labels to fit in. if you change margins to `par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))` they will fit fine.

Comment: Also, on a separate note 2.5 years as a member with 20 questions (all with answers) and zero number of accepted answers seems rather bad. You might want to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to accept answers.

Comment: @LyzandeR changing to 4,4,1,1 gives figure margin too large. I have changed the code to be self-contained Also I may have forgotten to accept answers. But the fact that I did not pursue the questions further  implies that my questions were answered.

Comment: @lyzandeR I did accept quite a few answers after you mentioned it. I usually upvoted it but did not accept it. Now  I have. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! It does show good manners, it gives both you and the person who answered reputation so that you can have more privileges on the site and most importantly it makes people who have the same question as you realise that there is indeed a solution that worked. So thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
value <- rnorm(300,mean=100,sd=20)
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(1,3)) 
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
boxplot(value, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE,ylim=c(0,160), 
        frame=F, col = "green1")
hist(value,breaks=40,xlab="Runs",ylab="Runs frequency", main = "Score")
```

[image]

Comment: As for this error it seems weird that you get a `margin too large` error since first of all the above worked for me as you can see with margins `c(4,4,1,1)` and keep in mind that the default is `c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1`.

Comment: This is really odd. I get the "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" when I run it in Rstudio. When I ran it in normal R console it seemed to work fine.

Comment: I am running it in Rstudio too and got no error. Do you have the latest version in Rstudio? maybe that is the problem. I am using: `Version 0.98.1056`

Comment: Yes. It is 0.98.1091. This is puzzling. I cut and paste your code in Rstudio and I get the error. Will need to debug in the morning. But I have observed that Rstudio does behave erratically with plots.

Comment: It does sometimes yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much better to have both the histogram and the boxplot using the same axis (in the question and previous answer a given value in the boxplot is not aligned with a the same value in the histogram).

So I think it would be better to use `ggMarginal` from [package ggExtra](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggExtra)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra) 

value <- rnorm(300,mean=100,sd=20) # your value
df <- data.frame(value) # I store it in a data.frame to be used with ggplot

p <- ggplot(df,
       aes(x = value)) +
  geom_point(    # ggMarginal works with scatterplots, so we create it
    aes(y = 20), # this value is arbitrary, just to be inside the plotting area
    alpha = 0) + # not to be printed
  geom_histogram()

ggMarginal(p, type = "boxplot", margins = "x")
```

[Thanks to Z.Lin for her answer in this question, which helped me first on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853139/how-to-add-a-boxplot-to-a-histogram-using-ggmarginal-in-r)

[image]