# How to add a boxplot to a histogram using ggMarginal in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, boxplot

I would like to draw a histogram with a density curve and then put a boxplot above the top margin. I know how to do this using the `hist()`, `boxplot()` and `layout()` functions, or using functions from the `ggplot2` and `grid` packages.  However, I am looking for a specific solution using `ggplot2` and the `ggMarginal()` function within the `ggExtra` package. Let's simulate some data before I present my problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
set.seed(1234)
vdat = data.frame(V1 = c(sample(1:10, 100, T), 99))
vname = colnames(vdat)[1]
boxplot(vdat[[vname]], horizontal = T)
```

To note, I explicitly insert an outlier 99 into a sample of numbers from 1 to 10. Hence, when I draw the boxplot, 99 should be displayed as an outlier.

I can easily draw a histogram using `ggplot2`.

```
p = ggplot(data=vdat, aes_string(x=vname)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=stat(density)),
                         bins=nclass.Sturges(vdat[[vname]])+1,
                         color="black", fill="steelblue", na.rm=T) +
  geom_density(na.rm=T) +
  theme_bw()
p
```

When I try to use `ggMarginal` to add a marginal boxplot, the added boxplots are not right.

```
p1 = ggMarginal(p, type="boxplot")
p1
```

The boxplot on the right might be right. But the one on top, which is the very one I need, is definitely wrong. The outlier 99 is not there and the median is clearly not right.

When I try not to provide `p1`, but the original data, `x`, and `y` as suggested by the help documentation, I get the right boxplot but the histogram is now gone.

```
p2 = ggMarginal(data=vdat, x=vname, y=NA, type="boxplot", margins="x")
p2
```

How can I combine the correct parts of p1 and p2 such that I have the histogram from p1 and the boxplot from p2?

I am trying something like

```
p1 + p2
```

or

```
ggMarginal(p1, data=vdat, x=vname, y=NA, type="boxplot", margins="x")
```

But they are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `ggMarginal`'s documentation, `p` is expected to be a ggplot *scatterplot*. We can insert the following line as the first geom layer in `p`:

```
geom_point(aes(y = 0.01), alpha = 0)
```

`y = 0.01` was chosen as a value within the existing plot's y-axis range, and `alpha = 0` ensures this layer isn't visible.

Running your code with this `p` should give you the boxplot with outlier.

```
p <- ggplot(data=vdat, aes_string(x=vname)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = 0.01), alpha = 0) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=stat(density)),
                 bins=nclass.Sturges(vdat[[vname]])+1,
                 color="black", fill="steelblue", na.rm=T) +
  geom_density(na.rm=T) +
  theme_bw()

p1 = ggMarginal(p, type="boxplot", margins = "x")
p1
```

[image: plot]

By the way, I don't think it really makes sense to plot a boxplot to the right in this instance, since you have not assigned any variable to `y`.